# BER-TLV open source library for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, smartcard, tlv

I intend to parse BER-TLV format from smart card response to interpret the data.

it similar like [JACCAL](http://jaccal.sourceforge.net/), but in Objective-C or C++

Can anyone give reference any open source project or any reference to do this?

Comment: I did not see any BER parsing/encoding in JACCAL you pointed to. ISO 7816-4 requires an extremely limited subset of BER parsing/encoding (and, funny enough, no ASN.1 definitions) so you might want to create a few helper classes and methods instead.

Comment: Botan seems to have a small BER parsing facility.

Comment: I recently parsed BER TLV responses from smart card by referring to the tokend project. I ended up writing my own functions but relied heavily on tokend project for the length parsing. A thing to note is that length can occupy 1,2,3 or 4 bytes. I don't have access to my code right now. I will try posting it later tonight,

Comment: thank you! I could create my own function if i can get reference on how to do. please do post.

Comment: Hi, i want to use the first library https://github.com/chrisridd/asn1-dump/ to do BER-TLV decoding but i cannot find an example how to use it. I would appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a project decode the ASN.1 BER format.
https://github.com/chrisridd/asn1-dump/

main logic located in this file:
https://github.com/chrisridd/asn1-dump/blob/master/berd.m

And if have enough time, it's not hard to write you own decoder after you read the standard:
http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf
http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html

decode flow is like this:
read in Tag, Length, Value sequence.

- From Tag you will get

  - Data Class, usually be Universal(predefined type in standard like "Boolean","Sequence"...)
            and context-specific (to distinguish different field with same type).
  - Primitive (like boolean and integer) or Constructed (usually is sequence).
    because constructed type can contains Primitive or Constructed type.
    maybe need recursive decoding.
  - Tag Number, determine data types (boolean? integer? bitstring?)
- Length:

  - determine length of the contents to decode into (maybe need recursively decoding).
  - length has two form (short and long). you'd better support both.
- Value: the real value to read in current TLV level. 
       if this is a constructed data(like sequence), the Value will contains internal level of TLV.

In the end of standard (http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf) there is an image shows multiple level TLV, maybe can better help you to understand BER.

After you read the standards, the best way is:
1) find some GUI viewer to look some BER Certificate file, to get familar with it. google "ASN.1 viewer" to find.
2) start to look the code https://github.com/chrisridd/asn1-dump/blob/master/berd.m

Comment: Hi, i want to use the first library https://github.com/chrisridd/asn1-dump/ to do BER-TLV decoding but i cannot find an example how to use it. I would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Hi @Sarah, download the code in the github, and open in xcode, and build it, and run. you will got an application "ASN.1 dump" running. Using the File->open to open the *.cer file in http://www.swview.org/sites/swview.org/files/x.509-sample-keys-and-certificates.zip  and see the showed winodw for expanded asn.1 structures.

Because *.cer files is in BER format.

Comment: @Sarah, contact me if you need more help on skype (id: whunmr)

Answer (score 1):

How about tlve? http://tlve.sourceforge.net/

Apple's Tokend seems useful too: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Tokend/Tokend-36720/PIV/TLV.cpp

jayacard on sourceforge is another project that dealt with this, now seems abandoned, but source is here: http://www.codeforge.com/read/7149/tlv.c__html